# Distinguish "belongs to" from "is of type" relationships in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys, relationships

I have been baffled by this question for quite a while, but haven't been able to get an answer by Googling.

I was wondering if there is a way to distinguish one-to-many database relationships between the following two types (in traditional relational database management systems - my primary interest lies with SQL Server):

- **Belongs to**: a relationship where the depending rows in the foreign key table actually cannot exist without the row in the primary key table. An example here would be the customer/order relationship, where an order without its customer is meaningless - deleting the customer means deleting his orders.
- **Is of certain type**: a relationship where the row in the foreign key table uses the primary key table row more like an attribute. Such an example would be the customer/account manager relationship - deleting the account manager does not entail deleting the customers he used to handle (please do not argue why it's good practice NOT to delete data for historical reasons in this case).

Is there some way to treat these two differently? As such, are there any good practices?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT - Why I am asking: I am building a generic application that "scans" the database for unknown (at compile time) entity types (tables) and their relationships. If I could "describe" that a certain relationship is of either type **then** I would decide how the application should behave at each occasion.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, though this kind of distinction is usually important when you work with conceptual / logical data models. On physical level, such differences aren't always apparent.

Consider the following diagram:

[image]

There are 3 types of foreign key relationships here:

1. Identifying (migrated) key. The PK from the Operations migrates into the AccountOperations, making it essentially an extension. It's a 1:1 relationship, because key in both tables is the same.
2. Non-identifying key. Data in the AccountOperations depends on ClientAccounts and makes no sense without its parent.
3. Non-key relationship. The Documents table has an AccountId attribute, but it's optional, which allows for creation of "anonymous" documents. Depending on the business requirements, you can even allow the client accounts to be deleted without removing their documents.

Comment: Thanks, Roger. So, if I get this straight, any distinction is implemented by code, or otherwise at the application level. There is no way of separating relationship types in the database.

Comment: The foreign key constraint, per se, is always the same, yes. The main difference comes from the referencing column(s) - whether they are part of the primary key, and whether they are mandatory.